# how to make a nested list to a matrix without using numpy and bracket

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, nested-lists

```
a=[10*['-']]*10
print(a)
[['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],..]
```

how to make the "a" into a matrix without bracket and, finally turn something like this:

```
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
```

I want to use the join function!!

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Did you _try_ using join?

Comment: If you're planning on changing any of the elements of your "matrix", you're going to be in for a surprise.

Comment: I want to use turn "a" into a string matrix, because I am creating a class, make  the __str__ function return the string like this output, 'a 'should be a nested list, and __str__function need to return a string like this output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two calls to `.join()` -- one to handle space separating the dashes, and one to handle printing the grid out on multiple lines:

```py
print('\n'.join(' '.join('-' * 10) for _ in range(10)))
```

This outputs:

```py
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: Sir, I want to turn "a" to  this outputs(using join), not just create it by join

Comment: want to use turn "a" into a string matrix, because I am creating a class, make the str function return the string like this output, 'a 'should be a nested list, and __str__function need to return a string like this output!!

Comment: You can use the same structure, but you'll need to change `'-' * 10` to an expression that iterates over the row of the grid.